# Multithreading lazy initialization

Tags: java, multithreading, lazy-evaluation

I have a question about java multi-threading.

I have a class which has access to multiple threads.

```
Class A 
{
    private Object obj;

    public Object returnObject()
    {
       if(condition)
          return getObjectA();
       else
          return getObjectB();
    }

    public Object getObjectA()
    {
       obj = new Object()
       obj.setProperty("prp1");
    }

    public Object getObjectB()
    {
       obj = new Object()
       obj.setProperty("prp2");
    }
}
```

When there are multiple threads accessing getObj..(). Does it create problems with the "obj" state. Would there be undesired results?

Thanks SLaks and Peter,

I think the following will also solve the thread safety concerns:

```
public Object getObjectA()
{
  Object obj = new Object()
  obj.setProperty("prp1");  
  return obj;                                                                                   
}
```

Comment: @skaffman I assumed it was a placeholder for an actual, meaningful condition

Comment: When you use a field or variable, it is usually best to limit the scope to only where it is needed. In this case it may actually solve you problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

If two threads call different code paths in `returnObject()` simultaneously, it could run `getObjectB()` between the two statements in `getObjectA()` and end up calling `obj.setProperty("prp1");` on ObjectB.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will create problems (try the code to see what kind of problems, but data will be lost).
The simplest solution is to use a `synchronized` block.

Comment: Hi Peter, How about if i go for  public Object getObjectA()
{
   Object obj = new Object()
   obj.setProperty("prp1");                                                                                       return obj;
}

Answer (score 0):

Provided, the `if(true)` is not hard coded since this will fix the execution path where getObjA() is always invoked !

Yes, this code can run into race condition where the `obj`'s value can depend on the order of thread execution (ie which order the getObj..() is invoked by multiple threads).

You need to `synchronize` the access to the obj variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think that `getObjectA()` and `getObjectB()` should be declared as private, and the then you should use a synchronized block inside the `returnObject()` method, so something like this :

```
class A 
{

private Object obj;

public Object returnObject()
{

   Object result;
   synchronized (A.class) { 
   result = (true) ? getObjectA() : getObjectB();
   }
  return result;
}

private Object getObjectA()
{
   obj = new Object()
   obj.setProperty("prp1");
}

private Object getObjectB()
{
   obj = new Object()
   obj.setProperty("prp2");
}

}
```

*Obviously the **true** condition must be replaced with some condition ...*

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to change to code to **NOT** holds the '`obj`' as a data member as it is need to ve concurrently accessed.

There are several solutions:

1. Create the Object locally inside the functions
2. Use a ThreadLocal object that can "wraps" the 'obj' data member
3. Create the Object once and user `clone()` for every call locally to a local Object and edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but this is pretty simple to fix, since you are replacing `obj` every call, you clearly don't care about it, so try making the field `obj` just a local variable, like this:

```
Class A {
    public Object returnObject() {
       if (true)
           return getObjectA();
       return getObjectB();
    }

    public Object getObjectA() {
       Object obj = new Object()
       obj.setProperty("prp1");
       return obj;
    }

    public Object getObjectB() {
       Object obj = new Object()
       obj.setProperty("prp2");
       return obj;
    }
}
```

If this works for you, consider making these methods `static`.